# Does including an untrusted PHP file have security risks?

Tags: php, security

I'm writing a PHP application that needs to be able to extract strings from a PHP file. The easiest way I can think of to perform this task is to [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file via PHP. (I'd store the uploaded file in a temp folder to load it via include).

However, I'm having serious doubts about including PHP files that come from an untrusted source and might potentially contain malicious code. I'm not sure whether `include` executes PHP code or not, which would make a big difference, I think.

Here's an example of the expected format of a PHP file the user could upload (the arrays can be flat or nested as shown in this example):

```
return [
    'general' => [
        'dear_user' => 'Dear :user',
        'yours_sincerely' => 'Yours sincerely,',
        'signature_team' => 'The :team team.'
    ]
];
```

Would this be a safe approach or should I find another way?

Comment: Never trust user input. Never. Why not use an other syntax so you can check and parse the settings?

Comment: "_I'm not sure whether include executes PHP code or not_" You know there's an [include](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) manual for PHP?

Comment: If it's data they need to set, then why not store a JSON or XML file rather than code

Comment: @NigelRen that's not really a possibility since it's specifically for translation files used in other PHP projects.

Comment: @kerbholz I've read and even linked the manual in my question but it was not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, overread that you linked it. "_The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file._"

Comment: Not sure why this being translation related precludes you from using JSON, XML, or, well, you know, a format specialised for translations like [PO files.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext)

Comment: @deceze I understand what you mean but the project is more like a developer tool. The developer can upload translation files from new or existing codebases. Various formats are supported like JSON, iOS Strings, XML, ... one of the formats that need to be supported is a PHP file containing strings. It would be tedious to first transform a PHP file to JSON and then upload it. The tool should be able to do that for the user.

Comment: OK, that's starting to make more sense. Then I see two possibilities: use a PHP parser to parse the file into a syntax tree and extract the necessary information from it (and discard it entirely if it doesn't match what  you expect), or set up a PHP sandbox where you can `include` the file, but which is so tightened down and isolated that nothing bad could happen. You most certainly don't simply `include` the file in your main process.